# camel-dropbox put files error

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to upload files to dropbox, but, when I compile it doesn't works.

This is my code:

```
from("direct:start").log("Starting dropbox component...")
                .to("dropbox://put?accessToken="+dropboxAccessToken+
                "&clientIdentifier="+dropboxClientIdentifier+
                "&uploadMode=add&localPath=/"+directory+
                "&remotePath=/CamelProject")
                    .log("Ending dropbox component...");
```

And, this is the error:

```
/CamelProject exists on dropbox and is not a folder!
```

Yes, the "CamelProject" exists in dropbox, but is a folder! I change the remotePath to a new folder ("CamelProject2") that doesn't exists, but doesn't works either.

Also, is it possible to dont use the absolute localPath (c:/user/....) and use the relative localPath (from/files)?

@Edit:
I tried to use the get operation, it works, in parts. When I tried to download a unique file, it works. But, when I tried to download more than a file, doesn't works.

The code that doesn't works:

```
from("dropbox://get?accessToken="+dropboxAccessToken+ 
    &clientIdentifier="+dropboxClientIdentifier+
    "&remotePath=/CamelProject")
        .to("file://output/");
```

Also, I tried to delete the folder, it works, after I tried to delete a unique file and this doesn't works.
The code that doesn't works:

```
from("direct:start").to("dropbox://del?accessToken="+dropboxAccessToken+ 
    "&clientIdentifier="+dropboxClientIdentifier+
    "&remotePath=/CamelProject/1.xml").to("mock:result");
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried with latest release.

Comment: I was trying with 2.20.2. Now, I did a test with 2.19.4 and the error changed to:
    "/CamelProject does not exist or can't obtain metadata"